# Performing a Resumable Upload in PHP - Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I want to achieve [this workflow](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) from my server, using PHP and a service account. Basically, I just want to generate a resume URI on my server, send it on my client and do the upload from my client. But the PHP SDK doesn't provide a method to do this !

I do **not** want to use Signed URL, as they do not allow me to control the file being uploaded. I just want to make a simple POST, like described in the page I linked, using the credentials (the Bearer token) loaded by the PHP SDK.

Is there anyway to do this without re-coding the entire auth part ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reproduce the steps provided in [1] to save the resumable session URI using PHP?

If this is the case, I can think on that you may build a simple PHP POST request using the file_get_contents() function (use http_build_query() function [2] to generate a URL-encoded query string to specify POST variables).

For example, for a resumable session (as shown in the documentaion [1]):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
  "name": "myObject"
}
```

You may try a PHP script for making this POST request. A possible option for a PHP script would be similar to this:

```
<?php

    $post = http_build_query(array('name'=>'myObject')); // POST variable "name"

    // Create the HTTP Headers
    $headers = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n"."charset=UTF-8\r\n"."X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"."X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000\r\n",
            'content' => $post
            )
        );

    $s_context = stream_context_create($headers);

    $uri = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable', false, $s_context);

?>
```

Could you try this PHP script and post your results?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload

[2] http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php